# How to call an AppSync mutation with Cognito authentication using python?

Tags: python, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

Is it possible to calling an AppSync mutation with Cognito authentication using Python? How?

I am trying to use boto3, but I don't found a way to execute graphql operations.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/appsync.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn your API auth mode to be "API KEY" and call an AppSync mutation with http.

For example.

```py
import requests
import json

APPSYNC_API_KEY = 'da2-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/graphql",
    'x-api-key': APPSYNC_API_KEY,
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
}

def execute_gql(query):
    payload_obj = {"query": query}
    payload = json.dumps(payload_obj)
    response = requests.request("POST", APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL, data=payload, headers=headers)
    return response
```

Imagine you have a model called `Items` and you can easily make query like below:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(execute_gql("query { listItems { items { id name } } }").json())
```

Simply replace the string with the mutation operation.

Comment: What are the implications of changing the auth mode? Mine is AWS_IAM I am not sure what would break if I changed it on the fly. The original question seems to be for that auth mode as well.  If so and if this switch is not problem free then this is not a real answer.

Comment: I can't get past 403 "Missing authentication token" :-(

Comment: OP asked specifically for how to auth using cognito. "Change your API to use key authentication" isn't a valid answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that idToken from auth response is the only one you need to pass under the `Authorization` header. Nothing more is required. Auth middleware shouldn't be passed in the Transport object at all. Here is how it finally worked from my side:

```
import boto3
from gql import gql, Client as GQLClient
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport

username = "YOUR_USER_NAME"
password = "YOUR_PASSWORD"
authClientId = "YOUR_COGNITO_AUTH_APP_CLIENT_ID"
regionName = "YOUR_REGION_NAME"
appSyncEndpoint = "YOUR_APPSYNC_ENDPOINT"

def authenticate():
  cgClient = boto3.client("cognito-idp", region_name=regionName)
  response = cgClient.initiate_auth(
      ClientId=authClientId,
      AuthFlow="USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
      AuthParameters={"USERNAME": username, "PASSWORD": password},
  )
  return response["AuthenticationResult"]["IdToken"]


def make_client(idToken):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': idToken #<<<< Just an idToken
    }
    transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(url=appSyncEndpoint,
                                      headers=headers) #<<<< there is no `auth` parameter here at all
    client = GQLClient(transport=transport,
                    fetch_schema_from_transport=False)
    return client

creds = authenticate()
queryText = """mutation createMessage($message: String!) {
  createMessage(input: {message: $message}) {
    id
    message
    createdAt
  }
}"""
asClient = make_client(creds)
result = asClient.execute(gql(queryText))
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

[graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) supports AWS AppSync since [version 3.0.0rc0](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql/releases/tag/v3.0.0rc0).

It supports queries, mutation and even subscriptions on the realtime endpoint.

It supports IAM, api key and JWT (for Cognito for example) authentication methods.

The documentation is available [here](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/appsync.html)

Here is an example of a mutation using the API Key authentication:

```py
import asyncio
import os
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
from gql.transport.appsync_auth import AppSyncApiKeyAuthentication

# Uncomment the following lines to enable debug output
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


async def main():

    # Should look like:
    # https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appsync-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/graphql
    url = os.environ.get("AWS_GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT")
    api_key = os.environ.get("AWS_GRAPHQL_API_KEY")

    if url is None or api_key is None:
        print("Missing environment variables")
        sys.exit()

    # Extract host from url
    host = str(urlparse(url).netloc)

    auth = AppSyncApiKeyAuthentication(host=host, api_key=api_key)

    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url=url, auth=auth)

    async with Client(
        transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=False,
    ) as session:

        query = gql(
            """
mutation createMessage($message: String!) {
  createMessage(input: {message: $message}) {
    id
    message
    createdAt
  }
}"""
        )

        variable_values = {"message": "Hello world!"}

        result = await session.execute(query, variable_values=variable_values)
        print(result)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: The question is about AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS auth mode, not API_KEY. It's invalid answer

Comment: @zelibobla gql supports cognito auth. Did you check the linked documentation?

Comment: It supports, but your example is irrelevant as it's about API_KEY while you've been asked for AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS.